# Moving to [un]hide element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some jQuery I am trying to get working a specific way. I want to hide and unhide an element and put the focus on the exposed area once it is revealed. There is a link #welcomeselect that when clicked should expose the hidden element #welcome. If I click the link with the below code it will unhide the element only; if I click it again it will then and only then move to the revealed element. The custom reveal code I found on another site (scrollToAnchor); I just need to be able to move to the unhide element, the smooth transition is not a requirement. What am I doing wrong.

```
$('#welcomeselect').click(function(){
    $('#welcome').show();
scrollToAnchor("#welcome");
});

 // scroll handler http://bradsknutson.com/blog/smooth-scrolling-to-anchor-with-jquery/

 var scrollToAnchor = function( id ) {
     // grab the element to scroll to based on the name
     var elem = $("a[name='"+ id +"']");
     // if that didn't work, look for an element with our ID
     if ( typeof( elem.offset() ) === "undefined" ) {
         elem = $("#"+id);
     }
     // if the destination element exists
     if ( typeof( elem.offset() ) !== "undefined" ) {
         // do the scroll
         $('html, body').animate({
             scrollTop: elem.offset().top
         }, 1000 );
     }
     };

     // bind to click event - http://bradsknutson.com/blog/smooth-scrolling-to-anchor-with-jquery/

     $("a").click(function( event ) {            
         // only do this if it's an anchor link
         if ( $(this).attr("href").match("#") ) {                
            // cancel default event propagation
            event.preventDefault();              
            // scroll to the location
            var href = $(this).attr('href').replace('#', '')
            scrollToAnchor( href );              
         }           
    });
```

Comment: Please edit your question and remove all of those blank lines!

Comment: Done, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

This one moves while the element is being shown (you only had an extra hash in the id):

```
$('#welcomeselect').click(function(){
  $('#welcome').show();
  scrollToAnchor("welcome");
});
```

**Previous**

Here you go, this one moves only after the element is revealed:

```
$('#welcomeselect').click(function(){
  $('#welcome').show(function(){
    scrollToAnchor("welcome");
  });
});

var scrollToAnchor = function( id ) {
  // grab the element to scroll to based on the name
  var elem = $("a[name='"+ id +"']");
  // if that didn't work, look for an element with our ID
  if ( typeof( elem.offset() ) === "undefined" ) {
    elem = $("#"+id);
  }

  // if the destination element exists
  if ( typeof( elem.offset() ) !== "undefined" ) {
    // do the scroll

    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: elem.offset().top
    }, 1000 );

  }
};
```